# "Something will be available by some time"

Tags: meaning

Does

```
Something  will be available  by 3pm tomorrow.
```

mean it will become available after 3pm tomorrow, or between now and 3pm tomorrow?

I get the latter meaning, because "by" can mean the end time?

Thanks.

Comment: It will be available between now and 3pm tomorrow - see sense 7 on [Collins'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by?showCookiePolicy=true) entry for it.

Comment: This question is possibly off-topic - questions that can be answered solely using a dictionary are off-topic on ELL.

Comment: @jimsug Can you or your dictionary explain what mccjeff said  happens in real life? If no, please be modest.

Comment: I think that the most important feature of "by + time" is that the speaker is telling you that you will be notified when something will be available, but in any case the time is a safe time to expect delivery. For example: an auto mechanic will often say "I'll have your car ready by 3pm" and call you at 2pm saying you can get your car now.

Comment: I don't think I could find out what "by + time" means with a dictionary. If I wanted to write this in Chinese I would be over asking at Chinese SE.

Comment: @Tim while I appreciate your candour, please know that topics are defined so as not to flood the stack with definition requests. If you're still having a problem with the term _after_ researching its meaning, then please feel free to edit your question to reflect any issues you have understanding it. What mccjeff said does not exclude the dictionary definition. It completely explains what happens in real life. If I say _something will be ready by 12.01pm_, then I mean that it will be ready __at__, and possibly _before_ 12.01pm.

Comment: @jimsug, mccjeff, Phil: I think I understand why Tim (the OP)'s confusion happened. The usage of *by*, *before*, and *until* can trip non-native speaker easily. I think in this one, the tricky part is not quite the *by* by itself, but the part *be available*. Is *available* an event or a state? For example, it's natural to say *"I'll stay here until Friday."* (staying is a state), or *"I'll have to leave before Sunday."* (leaving is a punctual event). Now, is "be available" a state or an event? (more)

Comment: (continued) If we read it as a state, it would sound odd, because we usually don't use *by* with a state-like activity. To demonstrate how odd it could be, I think this sentence will at least sound iffy, *"I'll stay here by Monday."*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Well, it's really (in this case) - and I'm sorry to throw even more terminology into the mix - it's an attribute. And you can definitely use _by_ with an attribute. _I'll be there by midnight / I'll have to be here by midnight / I'll be tired by midnight / I'll be awake by midnight / I'll be dead by midnight_ All perfectly fine.

Comment: ... you can additionally use it with past tense of verbs, since they become attributes... _It'll be eaten by noon / It'll be cleaned by noon / It'll be gone by noon / It'll be laundered by noon / It'll be processed by noon_ Again, all perfectly fine, and all could also be called attributed of the "it".

Comment: @jimsug Thank you for the examples. I know they're all fine. The point is that to understand *by* when it's used with these kinds of state-like things (or attributes), we (learners) should think of it as changing from one state to another. And that change should happen before the *by*-phrase. The part of Tim's "between now and 3pm tomorrow" gave me the clue of the confusion, which might not be answerable by dictionaries. And that is what I'd like to help Tim to clarify the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14543/discussion-between-jimsug-and-damkerng-t)

Answer (score 1):

**General usage of *by + time***

In English, the preposition "by" + time generally means:

- not later than; before; (Collins [UK](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by?showCookiePolicy=true), [US](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/by?showCookiePolicy=true))

Note that, while it can mean *something* will happen *at* a specific time, it almost always implied that *something* will happen *at or before* a specific time. In fact, the preposition *at* is exactly what you would use to specify that something will occur at a specific time and no other.

**action + by + time**

You can verbs because they *become* attributes.

Compare:

- At midnight, I ran [ten kilometres].
- By midnight, I ran [ten kilometres].

In the first instance, the usual reading is that I started to run ten kilometres from midnight onwards.
In the second, the usual reading is that I had *finished* running ten kilometres *before* midnight.

Similarly, compare:

- The bell rang three times at noon.
- The bell rang three times by noon.
- I ate three pounds of salmon at 3pm.
- I are three pounds of salmon by 3pm.

**by + state/attribute**

You can use *by* with attributes, which can be adjectives. For instance:

- He grew to 135cm by the age of five
- He grew to 135cm at the age of five

In the first instance, he grows to 135cm before the age of five.
In the second instance, he became five years old, then promptly had a growth spurt and grew to 135cm in that moment.

Similarly:

- I'm painting this wall. It will be red by noon.

Obviously, I'm not going to wait until noon precisely and then paint the wall entirely red - I'll be painting it, and I think I'll finish *at or before* noon.

Answer (score 1):

> Your car/fixed-jewelry/pressed-shirts will be available by 3pm tomorrow.

To put it simply, this idiomatically means:

- Your item will not be available today.
- Your item will be available no later than 3pm tomorrow.
- You can plan on getting your item at 3 pm.
- You might be able to pick it up before 3pm, but you would need to call.

Note that if you want, for some things, you can ask if they can have it earlier.  For example, with prescriptions, one might be able to get it within one hour if one were to ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

In modern American English when someone uses that phrase they are implying that the implied item will be available at 3pm.

For example if someone says: "You car will be ready to be picked up from the mechanic by 12pm tomorrow" they are saying that you can go pick your car up at 12pm tomorrow.

Comment: so it doesn't say it will be available between 3pm tomorrow till when?

Comment: More accurately, I would say that it means _at or before_ - see sense 2 in [Collins' US](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/by?showCookiePolicy=true)

Comment: No. All it is saying is that the implied item will be ready at 3pm tomorrow onward. If the person said that you have until a certain time to pick the implied item up then you would have to pick the item up between 3pm(start time) and the time told told to you(end time)

Comment: @jimsug                                                      2 b. not later than   ⇒ "be back by ten o'clock"

Comment: It does not say before. In the US when someone says "Something  will be available  by 3pm tomorrow." then it is understood that the implied item will be available at 3pm.

Comment: Yes, but _at_ implies _not later than_... they're not at odds with each other, and your example is an edge case. What they're promising is it will be available at 3pm, but not later, right?

Comment: @jimsug On whether the implied item will be available after 3pm we would need to know more of the context. Generally when someone says "by" they mean at that exact time or after. Not before.

Comment: This may be based on a different reading of the definition - the UK entry (above as a comment to OP) has a better one. Essentially, "by" does not mean "at and only at the time specified", it means "at or before the time specified". Neither does it mean "at but not after the time specified", which I what I think you have (mis)understood the definition to mean. "by" does not make a comment on the state of affairs after the time, and it is assumed that the state remains after the specified time.

Comment: Yes you are partly correct. In American English that is spoken outside a dictionary "by" never means before.

Comment: There is a big difference between dictionary English and real world English.

Comment: @mccjeff, I disagree.  If the mechanic tells me my car will be ready "by 3pm", and I show up at 2:45, he may very well say "yep, your car is all done and ready to go".  In fact it may have been finished and sitting out in the parking lot for the last hour because he got to it sooner than expected.

Comment: @Hellion Yes true but we do not know that. Your implying that the car will be ready by then. We have no idea if it will or not. The mechanic said that the car will be ready by 3pm so then you should be there to pick it up at 3pm or after.